# What Live CD would you recommend to restore photos from a formatted HDD?

Tags: hard-drive, restore, livecd, photos

My hard drive was formatted. Do you know any Live CD that could help with restoring photos from it?

Answer (score 3):

[Hiren's BootCD](http://www.hirensbootcd.org/) contains many tools, one of them being SoftPerfect File Recovery. You can use that tool to recover files from a formatted hard drive.

Comment: Have you tried this to remove photoes from a formatted HDD?